# Error: unable to start debugging. Silverlight developer runtime is not installed. Please install matching version

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010

I have VS2010 and Silverlight SDK 3 and 4. I have created a sample application in vs2010 using SilverLight web application. When I press F5, the error is coming : **Error: unable to start debugging. Silverlight developer runtime is not installed. Please install matching version**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The SDK and the Developer Runtime are separate things - try uninstalling Silverlight (just the runtime, no need to uninstall SDK, Tools, etc...), and reinstalling just the Developer Runtime from here : http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=188039

Comment: @AustinLamb We also need to make sure that the `SDK` is **64bit** in case the **machine** also is

Answer (score 2):

Old question - but I just picked up an old silverlight project I am taking over and ran into this error.  After uninstalling and installing different versions (I have SDK5 now) the issue was that I was using Google Chrome version 47 which isn't supported (Version 42 and LATER is not supported).  Micorosoft Edge isn't supported either.  There's a little blurb about it at the bottom of this page: https://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/get-started/install/default.aspx?reason=unsupportedbrowser&_helpmsg=ChromeVersionDoesNotSupportPlugins&v=5.0.61118.0#